# Difference between the RamBam and Talmud Kiddushin 82a in list of jobs that posul a King/High Priest?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rambam, kohen-priest, employment, maseches-kiddushin

The Talmud in [Kiddushin 82a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=82&format=pdf) lists a bunch of professions that invalidate one from serving as a King or High Priest. The RamBam codifies this in [Hilchot Melachim 1:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=1&halocha=6&hilite=), but his list does not match the Talmud's.

Does anyone have any insight as to why there is a difference between the two lists, or why the RamBam seems to omit several of the jobs (e.g. cleaner, peddler, etc.)?

Comment: Hi Student_1 and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Your question would get a lot more attention and better answers if you sourced where in the Rambam you saw the list and enumerated the similarities and differences.

Answer (score 7):

(If you're in a rush, skip to the last paragraph.)

Let us first compare the texts to see what the discrepancies actually are. The Talmudic passage reads as follows:

**[Kiddushin 82a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=82&format=pdf)**

> תנו רבנן כל שעסקיו עם הנשים סורו רע כגון הצורפים והסריקים והנקורות
>   והרוכלין והגרדיים והספרים והכובסים והגרע והבלן והבורסקי אין מעמידים
>   מהם לא מלך ולא כהן גדול מאי טעמא לא משום דפסילי אלא משום דזיל
>   אומנותיהו
>
> Our Rabbis taught: He whose business is with women has a bad
>   character. E.g., goldsmiths, carders, [handmill] cleaners, pedlars,
>   wool-dressers, barbers, launderers, bloodletters, bath attendants and
>   tanners. Of these neither a king nor a High Priest may be appointed.
>   What is the reason? Not because they are unfit, but because their
>   profession is mean. ([Soncino traslation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kiddushin.pdf))

Rambam's codification of this reads as follows:

**[Hilchot Melachim 1:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=14904)**

> ואין מעמידין מלך ולא כהן גדול לא קצב ולא ספר ולא בלן ולא בורסי לא מפני
>   שהן פסולין אלא הואיל ואומנותן נקלה העם מזלזלין בהן לעולם
>
> Neither a butcher, barber, bath-attendant, nor a tanner should be
>   appointed king or High-Priest. This is not because of an inherent
>   fault, but because their professions are less prestigious, and the
>   people will always treat them lightly. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188345/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-1.htm))

We see here that the Talmud gives a list of 10 professions, while Rambam gives a list of four. Three out of the four that Rambam lists are listed by the Talmud; one is not.

So essentially what we have here is that Rambam removed seven professions from the list and added one profession to the list. Why did he do this?

[R. Simeon Ben Tzemach Duran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_ben_Zemah_Duran) addresses this in a responsum:

**[Tashbetz 1:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1381&pgnum=28)**

> וגם בענין מינוי המלכו' לא הזכירו הרמב"ם ז"ל שהוא כ' בפ' א' מה' מלכים
>   אין מעמידין לא מלך ולא כ"ג לא גרע ולא ספר ולא בלן ולא בורסקי הזכיר אלו
>   שהם מנוולים בכ"מ שהאומנות בעצמה היא מנוולת ומלוכלכת והשמיט האחרים ראה
>   הרב ז"ל במקומות אלו שהם אומניות משובחות וכתב לפי מקומו אע"פ שבתלמוד
>   מזכירין אותם לגנאי וזה סיוע לדברי שהכל לפי המקומות

Here he argues that certain professions are inherently lowly, while others depend on the time and place. Rambam therefore left out all the professions that he saw were not lowly in his time.

It should be noted that R. Duran's citation of Rambam has a different text from ours. He has גרע instead of קצב, in which case all of Rambam's examples are in fact from the Talmud. However, it appears that R. Duran's text is actually the correct one, as the Kafih edition notes that all manuscripts in his possession support גרע, and the Frankel edition notes that the majority of manuscripts have it as גרע (or some slight variation).

A different explanation is suggested by [R. Joseph Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo). He noticed a pattern in the professions that Rambam omitted. Specifically, Rambam omitted the first five professions. R. Karo thus explains that Rambam punctuated the Talmudic passage differently. Instead of understanding the entire passage beginning from תנו רבנן as one long statement, he breaks it up into two statements. The first statement is about professions that deal with women. The Talmud lists five professions. Then, starting from והספרים is a new statement referring to the lowly jobs that invalidate one as a king or high priest. Thus, according to R. Karo, the reason why Rambam left out some of the professions is that according to his understanding of the Talmud, those professions were never mentioned in the context of invalidating a king/high priest. Rambam left them out because those professions **do not** in fact invalidate someone.

R. Karo still has to deal with the fact that even after the first five professions, Rambam still omitted כובסים and גרע and added קצב. R. Karo suggests that Rambam had קצב *instead of* כובסים (presumably meaning that he had a different Talmudic text) and that he didn't have גרע (presumably another Talmudic textual variant). However, this as not as big of an issue as it seems, because as noted above, the text of Mishneh Torah actually does say גרע and does not say קצב – R. Karo was working from a faulty text – so the only thing that really needs explanation is the omission of כובסים.

**[Kessef Mishneh Hilchot Melachim 1:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=90378&rid=14904)**

> בסוף קידושין ת"ר כל שעסקו עם הנשים סורו רע הצורפין והסריקין והנקורות
>   והרוכלים והגרדין והספרים והכובסים והגרע והבלן והבורסקי אין מעמידין מהם
>   לא מלך ולא כ"ג מ"ט לא משום דפסילי אלא משום דזיל אומנותייהו וסובר רבינו
>   דהא דכל שעסקו עם הנשים לא שייך אלא עד הגרדיים ומספרים ואילך מיירי
>   לענין שאין מעמידין מלך ולא כ"ג ובמקום כובסין גריס קצבים ולא גריס גרע

[R. Nachum Rabinovitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum_Rabinovitch) in his edition of Mishneh Torah (Yad Peshutah) offers an explanation similar to R. Karo's but taken to the next level. He notes that our printed versions of the Talmud apparently have the wrong text. He points out that the Cambridge manuscript T-S AS 75.58 actually has the beraita cited by the Talmud as two separate beraitot.<sup>1</sup> The first beraita is about professions that deal with women, and six professions are named. The second beraita is about lowly professions that invalidate one as a king or high priest, and four professions are named. These four professions are precisely the four professions mentioned by Rambam (in the correct text of Mishneh Torah mentioned above).

> ברם ראה גירסת כ"י קיימברידג' שם ישנן שתי ברייתות נפרדות' הברייתא
>   הראשונה בעניין מי שסורו רע והברייתא השנייה בעניין העמדת מלך וכהן גדול
>   וזו רשימה המתאימה בדיוק לסדר בעלי המלאכה שנקט רבינו תנו רבנן כל שעסקו
>   עם הנשים סורו רע כגון הצרופים והסי<..>קים והנקורות והגירדיים והספרים
>   והכובסים תנא הגרע והספר והבלן והבורסי אין מעמידים מהן לא מלך ולא כהן
>   גדול לאו משום דפסילי אילא משום דזילא אומנותיהו

("T-S AS 75.58" should appear after "'קיימברידג", but I can't put it in the middle of the Hebrew quote without ruining the format.)

R. Rabinovich's interpretation can be bolstered by a parallel passage elsewhere in Rabbinic Literature. In [Tanna Devei Eliyahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanna_Devei_Eliyahu) we find a similar statement about disqualifying professions, in which the first half about professions dealing with women is entirely absent:

**[Seder Eliyahu Zuta Chapter 16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21972&st=&pgnum=137)**

> הגרע והבלן והבורסקי אין מעמידין מהן לא מלך ולא נשיא ולא כהן גדול ואין
>   מוסרין להם דבר שיש בו שררה לרבים ואין מעמידין מהן אפוטרופסין ליתומין
>   רבי יוסי אומר פסולין לעדות הם ורשב"ג אומר אין נושאין מהן נשים לכהונה

Notably, the old text version (printed on the side in the above link) has "והבורסי" which is even closer to Rambam's text.

**Thus, the simplest answer to your question of why Rambam deviated from the Talmudic list, is that once you have the correct texts of both the Mishneh Torah and the Talmud there are actually no differences.**

---

<sup>1. R. Rabinovitch also notes that even in our corrupt Talmudic text the vestiges of the two beraita split can be detected, for we see that the professions in the first half are plural, while those in the second half are singular:</sup>

> וכן בנוסח הדפוסים השתמר זכר שיש כאן שתי ברייתות שפתחה הברייתא בלשון
>   רבים צורפים סריקים וסיימה בלשון יחיד והגרע והבלן אלא ודאי שהחיבור בין
>   שתי הברייתות הוא שיבוש